# Hide url parameters in php

Tags: php

I am not getting the way to hide the values that are passing through url in php. Clicking over a link , page redirects plus parameters are also shown on url .For eg:-

```
/localhost/oops/edit.php?id='1'
```

but I want to hide the data after `?` while redirecting.

Comment: u have to use POST method while posting the data

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to use a form and POST if the page your are logging into is controlled by a 3rd party. Try to use hidden input type while login. Maybe that'll work for you. For example:

```
<form action="http://mywebsite.com/login.aspx" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="check" value="uid" />
   <input type="hidden" name="user" value="adam" />
   <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="pass1234" />
   <input type="hidden" name="profile" value="profile" />
   <input type="hidden" name="defaultdatabaseb" value="database" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: And for the notice -> don't use GET.